# Cannot Convert 'char (*)[200]' to 'char**'

Tags: c++, arrays, function, compiler-errors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void ArrayTimesThree(char*, const char*);

int main()
{
    char s1[200], s2[200], circleword[200];
    cin.getline(s1, 200);
    cin.getline(s2, 200);

    ArrayTimesThree(circleword, s1);
    cout<<circleword[1];
}

void ArrayTimesThree(char *dest[], char *source[])
{
    *dest[0] = NULL;
    strcat(*dest, *source);
    strcat(*dest, *source);
    strcat(*dest, *source);
}
```

> main.cpp|21|error: cannot convert 'char (*)[200]' to 'char**' for argument '1' to 'void ArrayTimesThree(char**, char**)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is really just because your initial ***declaration*** of `ArrayTimesThree` (which is the 'correct' one) doesn't match the ***definition*** you later give (which is wrong, in fact). Change your definition as below and it works:

```
void ArrayTimesThree(char* dest, const char* source) // Needs to be the same as in the previous declaration!
{
    dest[0] = '\0';   // Don't assign a string pointer to NULL! Instead, set its first character to the nul character
//  strcpy(dest, ""); // ALternatively, use strcpy with an empty string to clear "dest"
    strcat(dest, source); // strcat takes char* and const char* arguments ...
    strcat(dest, source); // ... so there is no need to 'deference the values ...
    strcat(dest, source); // ... now that the argument types have been 'corrected'
}
```

Incidentally, I notice that the input value for `s2` in your `main` function is never actually used … is this what you intend, for now?

Comment: Yes, I was going to finish the program after I see it working in that stage :)  . So, from what I understood, you should not put a function's parameter as "pointer to an array", similar to what I did. You should just put a pointer to the type of the variable, right ?

Answer (score 2):

You're passing ArrayTimesThree a char*, however, in the method signature you're telling it to expect a char**. Don't forget that that using the `[]` operator counts as a dereference. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void ArrayTimesThree(char*, char*);

int main()
{
    char s1[200], s2[200], circleword[200];
    cin.getline(s1, 200);
    cin.getline(s2, 200);

    ArrayTimesThree(circleword, s1);
    cout<<circleword[1];

    return 0;
}

void ArrayTimesThree(char *dest, char source[])
{
    dest[0] = '\0';
    strcat(dest, source);
    strcat(dest, source);
    strcat(dest, source);
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm not sure what exactly you're expecting out of this code, so I cannot guarantee the logic is correct; however, this will take care of your compiler errors and seems to function correctly for how the code is written.